# Is this solution for the limit correct?

Tags: limits

We have the limit:

> $\lim_{t \downarrow 0} t^{(t^a)}$ with $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

My solution was as follows:

We know that $\lim_{t \downarrow 0} t^a = 0^a = 0$ with $a \in \mathbb{R}$. So we have $\lim_{t \downarrow 0} t^{(t^a)} = \lim_{t \downarrow 0} t^0 = 1.$

Is this correct? Am I allowed to say that  $\lim_{t \downarrow 0} t^{(t^a)} = \lim_{t \downarrow 0} t^0$?

Comment: Maybe  $a$ is negative.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Oh, I see. Then I'm totally out of ideas how to do this limit. I guess this one only works for positive $a$.

Comment: Negative is no problem. Argue that  the limit is $0$ in that case.

Comment: @AndréNicolas But doesn't $\lim_{t \downarrow 0} t^a = \infty$ for negative $a$?

Comment: Yes it does. That makes  $t^{t^a}$ approach $0$, very fast.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Of course, if you square a number less than $1$ it will approach $0$, so if you square it hundreds of times it will approach $0$ very fast. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The analysis, and answer, depends on the value of the constant $a$, so we consider various cases.

(i) Suppose that $a$ is negative. Then as $t$ approaches $0$ from the right, $t^a$ becomes very large. So $t^{t^a}$ approaches $0$, fast.

(ii) Suppose next that $a=0$. Then for $t$ positive, $t^a$ is identically $1$. Thus when $a=0$ our function, for positive $t$, is simply $t$. It follows that in the case $a=0$  the function $t^{t^a}$ has limit $0$ as $t$ approaches $0$ from the right.

(iii) Finally, let $a\gt 0$. I think the limit is less obvious in this case. Your limit-taking procedure, which involved taking the limit of part of the expression, is not justified, and can give the wrong answer. However, here it *happened* to give the right numerical answer.

We can express $t^{t^a}$ as $\exp(t^a\ln t)$. Now find what happens to $t^a\ln t$ as $t\to 0^+$. Maybe it will be clearer if we let $w=1/t$. Then
$$t^a\ln t=-\frac{\ln w}{w^a}.$$
In the long run $\ln w$ grows more slowly than any positive power of $w$, so $\lim_{w\to\infty}-\frac{\ln w}{w^a}=0$.  This can be verified in various ways, including L'Hospital's Rule.

Finally, because $t^a\ln t\to 0$, we conclude that $t^{t^a}\to \exp(0)$.  So our limit is $1$.

Comment: Yes, I removed the comment after you added the explanation (it was clear). Thanks, I fully understand the problem now.